# Formatting a laptop with UEFI

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi

I have a Lenovo laptop with UEFI boot that came with Windows 10 installed. I have tried several times to install Ubuntu on an dual boot scheme with it but I never got it to work (because of the UEFI and Windows erasing the grub).

But since I got fed up with Windows, I'm considering formatting everything in the hard-drive and installing Ubuntu, keeping the Windows in a virtual machine. However, because of the UEFI boot, I'm not sure if it'll work. (There's a weird partition with around 200 MB and another with about 1 GB that I can't be sure if I should delete.)

I'm not sure if it's important, but here's my list of partitions (sorry that it's in Portuguese, but it should still be understandable):

[image]

My question is: can I format everything and install Ubuntu normally? Are there some steps that I need to be careful with?

Comment: Yes, you can. As a matter of fact, the installer will do it for you if you select the option to delete evrything and install Ubuntu.

Comment: *"because of the UEFI and Windows erasing the grub"* What do you mean by that? Can you back up that claim with actual data (from the filesystem of the EFI partition, output of efibootmgr)? The UEFI firmware on several computers does not behave as expected. Please post the maker and model number of the computer or mainboard.

Comment: @LiveWireBT The model is a Lenovo G40, but I don't have the laptop on me to post the mainboard. My attempts happened about a year ago, so I don't really remember the specifics. I posted a couple of questions here about it. Here's [one of them](http://askubuntu.com/questions/753179/bootrepair-doesnt-start-when-trying-to-recover-boot).

Comment: The information about the maker and model is enough to suggest checking for this post: http://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/44694.html (Title: Microsoft aren't forcing Lenovo to block free operating systems)

Comment: @LiveWireBT Great read. But due to my lack of knowledge in this area I have to ask: does that mean that following the "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" option will result in a computer that doesn't boot? (By the way, you're welcome to post an answer if you want).

Comment: It's likely that the non-Windows OS will not boot and you would have to reinstall Windows. I haven't seen the problem first hand, you better check the laptop's UEFI setup sceen options to be certain if your laptop is affected or not.

Comment: Chances are Windows did not delete anything; instead, chances are you ran into what I call a *boot coup,* as I describe [here.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootcoup.html) That page is part of my rEFInd documentation, and so is most applicable if you use it; but the same principles and solutions can be used (with minor modifications) if you use Ubuntu's default GRUB to boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As CelticWarrior mentioned in the comments, ff you are going to remove Windows and install and retain Ubuntu only, you would best just run the LiveUSB and install Ubuntu using the Install option to use the Entire Disk.  The Installer will delete everything on the disk by automatically reformatting and creating the partitions that it will user.

Look at the [Ubuntu Install Guide](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop).

Notice the first option is **Erase disk and install Ubuntu**.  That is the one you would choose to have your computer automatically format and partition your hard drive.

Comment: I'm just worried that because of the UEFI thing, that won't be enough to make it work. Will the installer automatically figure out that it should do an UEFI installation?

Comment: Yes.  Just make sure you boot the computer in EFI mode.  It will perform the install based on the mode you boot to.  If you boot into legacy it will preform a legacy install.  If you boot EFI it will perform a UEFI install.

Comment: Worked perfectly!

Comment: Great!  Enjoy the world of Linux!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have both Windows and Linux, make a clean install of Windows first and then insert Ubuntu LiveUSB. Grub will be set as default after the install.

Otherwise, if you want to have only Linux it is better to erase disk and install Ubuntu. Everything will go as expected.